# Laravel fatal error: Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Auth\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to start using laravel php framework. I'm trying to just call the index file and I get this error message.

> C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\lara\application\public\index.php
>
> Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Auth\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\lara\application\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php on line 357
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

Can anyone shine some light on what this means?

Comment: I'm using php strom if that makes a difference.

Comment: you must go to /yor_project_adress/public

Comment: try run in terminal php artisan clear:compiled

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by go to /your_project_address/public? The file index.php that I am trying to run is in that folder? @ImtiazPabel I tried doing as you said and I got "Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory' not found in C:\xampp"

Comment: first remove bootstrap/cache/services.php then run php artisan clear:compiled may be it will help you.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel tried still getting : Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory' not found in C:\xampp

Comment: remove full vendor folder then again composer install

Comment: @ImtiazPabel that did the trick. I owe you one. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Niall i make this solution as answer,please make this accepted that will helpful for others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Illuminate\Auth\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory` may not copied in your project,that why this is happening.So you need to be

```
Step 1 : Remove full vendor folder 
Step 2 : Run from your terminal composer install
```

Comment: I also had to delete `/bootstrap/cache/services.php`, `/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php`, in addition to `/vendor`.