# Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to run my Laravel project using artisan serve but I am getting the following error:

```
In ServiceProvider.php line 8:
                                                                         
  Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider' not found

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I also tried deleting the vendor folder and reinstalling,but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: hello. Maybe you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410757/laravel-fatal-error-fatal-error-interface-illuminate-auth-illuminate-contract) it might be a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I just solve the problem.
just run: composer update

Comment: Please share some explanation such that others can learn from your answer - running `composer update` should never be done randomly